# 大変　How to choose correct meaning

Tags: words

A man has just opened his newspaper and pulled out a bundle of leaflets. He then says:

> 「いっぱい広告が入ってるなァ。お歳暮も大変だよなァ」
>   It's full of adverts. The year-end gifts are (also?) great/terrible.

I've never properly understood 大変. How do I know if the man is happy or upset by the year-end gifts? My guess is that he's not happy because leaflets in newspapers are a pain, but it's not clear to me at all.

Comment: What else do we know about the man? Is there more to the conversation? I think we need a little more context to truly know what he means here.

Comment: This is how the story starts. Afterwards he starts reading the newspaper. I think from the previous story he's quite an enthusiastic, excitable man, but there's no context here that really helps me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I agree that 大変 doesn't necessary indicate the man is happy or not, I'd say that **he is feeling some sort of sympathy**, because, in this case, 大変 refers to the *competition* among companies **being tough**.
What do I mean by *competition*? Considering lots of people give out end-year gifts in Japan, those companies must be trying their best to *win* as big sales as they can.

Comment: そうですね・・お歳暮商戦のことでしょうね、たぶん・・

Comment: I must assume from the comment and upvotes that this is correct. I guess I'm missing some cultural knowledge that makes this more obvious?

Comment: I thought the man is implying **「お歳暮商戦」** which you might want to know. In the near-end of the year, Japanese gives away the gift to those who have been helpful / kind to them (or お世話になった人, to be precise.) There are so many items purchased as gifts in this season, which is a huge chance for those stores to get big sales - the stores makes desperate efforts to make the best of it. This competition has become so intense that we use the word "商戦" (*sales war*) for it. While the man isn't really involved in selling, he feels the hard work of stores from those ads.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's neither of those definitions. I think in this sentence it has definition 2 from [here](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/134412/meaning/m0u/%E5%A4%A7%E5%A4%89/):

> 物事が重大であること。また、そのさま。「―な失敗をする」「大型台風の通過で―な被害を受ける」

and the sentence means something like:

> It's full of adverts. There's way too many year-end gifts too.

Answer (score 3):

It's still ambiguous if it refers to customers or sellers but anyway, you can take sense of costing too much or a lot to do into account.